# Hiding Jackson type info on certain (fields) situations?

Tags: jackson

The example

**Java:**

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(  
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,  
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
            property = "@type")
    public class Pet{ 
        String name;
    }

    public class Dog extends Pet{}
    public class Cat extends Pet{}

    public class PetHouse {
        List<Pet> pets;
    }

    public class BarkingData {
        int decibels;
        Dog dog;
    }
```

**JSON Serialization**

```
    petHouse = {
        pets :
        [
            {'@type': 'Dog', 'name':'Droopy'},
            {'@type': 'Cat', 'name':'Scratchy'},
            {'@type': 'Dog', 'name':'Snoopy'}
        ]
    }

    barkingData = {
        decibels:15,
        dog:{'@type':'Dog', 'name':'Droopy'}
    }
```

**The Question**
Class BarkingData has a field of type Dog (cats don't bark do they). Is it possible to tell Jackson not to include typeInfo for instances where that type can be "hinted" from the declaring field ?

So that the output of Barking data looks like :

```
    barkingData = {
        decibels:15,
        dog:{'name':'Droopy'}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea that you know the dynamic type (actual type) of this field because the static type is `Dog` and not `Animal` only works if there are no subclasses of `Dog`. If you make the `Dog` class `final`, then Jackson knows it can safely leave out the type info.

Additionally, you can override Jackson's type info settings, in more complex ways, for fields of static type `Dog,` by adding a `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation to the definition of the `Dog` class.